# Copying Direct3D11 texture on other D3D11 device

Tags: direct3d11

I have a handle to ID3D11Texture2D, but no access to it's ID3D11DeviceContext or ID3D11Device. I want to copy that texture to other texture on other ID3D11Device. Texture is not created with any sharing flags. If I try to copy with ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource I get warning "D3D11 CORRUPTION parameter does not match device". How can I copy the texture or it's contents? I guess this is possible, since for example OpenVR API only uses texture handle without any context.

Comment: If you don't use sharing, you have to copy it back via CPU memory which is going to be terribly slow.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn To copy texture to CPU I would need to copy it to staging texture first? And to do that I would need device context which I don't have?

Comment: You can't do any copies without the immediate device context.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn In theory it looks like that, but in practise copying between device context works just fine if I ignore debug flags.

Comment: Which means you are using undefined behavior that may work on some driver/video cards, but not others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a texture is not created with the sharing flag, you cannot use it between two devices.

But you have the texture object, that is a `ID3D11DeviceChild` and it is enough to get access to `ID3D11DeviceChild::GetDevice` to retrieve the device and by extension `ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext`

Now that you have access to the device and the context, you can create an extra texture with the sharing flag `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED` on the original device or your own and retrieve back the object on the other one with `ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource`. And finally copy the original texture to the new object with `CopyResource`

Don't forget that all theses `Get` add reference to the objects that need to be released once you are done with them.

Comment: Works like a charm and solves my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi galop1n, can I ask you for your help, I've tried what you had described here but without any success. Here is my original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342736/copy-ffmpeg-d3dva-texture-resource-to-shared-rendering-texture. Thank you for any kind of help