# Copy ffmpeg d3dva texture resource to shared rendering texture

Tags: ffmpeg, rendering, textures, directx-11, render-to-texture

I'm using ffmpeg to decode video via d3dva based on this example https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/hw_decode.c. I'm able to succesfully decode video. What I need to do next is to render decoded NV12 frame. I have created directx rendering texture based on this example https://github.com/balapradeepswork/D3D11NV12Rendering and set it as shared.

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_NV12;              // Pixel format
    texDesc.Width = width;                          // Width of the video frames
    texDesc.Height = height;                        // Height of the video frames
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;                          // Number of textures in the array
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;                          // Number of miplevels in each texture
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE; // We read from this texture in the shader
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

    hr = device.CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, null, &nv12Texture);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        error("Failed to create NV12 texture (hr: %s)", hr);
        return false;
    }

    // QI IDXGIResource interface to synchronized shared surface.
    IDXGIResource dxgiResource;
    nv12Texture.QueryInterface(&IID_IDXGIResource, cast(void**)&dxgiResource);

    // obtain handle to IDXGIResource object.
    hr = dxgiResource.GetSharedHandle(&sharedHandle);
    dxgiResource.Release();
    dxgiResource = null;

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        error("Failed to create NV12 texture shared handle (hr: %s)", hr);
        return false;
    }
```

I'm then trying to copy nv12 from ffmpeg texture to my rendering texture. exactly as ffmpeg does in function [d3d11va_transfer_data](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a24a1523e8d7f13e244c5f11e3a9e0cfd6998cfa/libavutil/hwcontext_d3d11va.c#L366).

```
    ID3D11Texture2D hwTexture = cast(ID3D11Texture2D)frame.data[0];

    ID3D11Device hwDevice;
    hwTexture.GetDevice(&hwDevice);

    ID3D11DeviceContext hwDeviceCtx;
    hwDevice.GetImmediateContext(&hwDeviceCtx);

    ID3D11Texture2D sharedTexture;

    HRESULT hr = device.OpenSharedResource(sharedHandle, &IID_ID3D11Texture2D,cast(void**) &sharedTexture);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        error("Failed to obtaion open shared resource.");
        return;
    }

    int index = cast(int)frame.data[1];
    hwDeviceCtx.CopySubresourceRegion(sharedTexture, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwTexture, index, null);
```

But the rendering window is just green no error no FAILED hr result nothing. I'm able render frames when I'm using sw decoder I just create texture with D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC and D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE.

Here us desc of each texture.

```
hwTexture desc D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC(1280, 720, 1, 20, 103, DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC(1, 0), 0, 512, 0, 0)
nv12Texture desc D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC(1280, 720, 1, 1, 103, DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC(1, 0), 0, 8, 0, 2)
sharedTexture desc D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC(1280, 720, 1, 1, 103, DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC(1, 0), 0, 8, 0, 2)
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Try to use AVD3D11VADeviceContext *device_hwctx = ctx->device_ctx->hwctx; (with an appropriate cast) instead of taking the device context from the texture. The ctx is the AVCodecContext that you create by avcodec_alloc_context3. Also try to set D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE for nv12Texture.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for you comment but this did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i finally figured out what is wrong, the problem is that OpenSharedResource is called from device instead of hwDevice.